# How display the spell out of an amount with currency details in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to spell out WooCommerce order total amount, in my `invoice.php` template file can reach order total amount.

First I tried:

```
$total = $order->get_total();
<?php echo ( $total ); ?> - 

<?php 
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format($total); ?>
```

The order total displayed is **225.00** and the spell out display is: **two hundred twenty-five**

---

**Edit:**

I found the following solution:

```
<?php  $number = $order->get_total() ;

$formatter = new NumberFormatter('tr', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

$formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%financial");

echo $formatter->format($number); ?>
```

But the result shows like that:  **two hundred twenty-five**

The desired display should be: **two hundred twenty-five turkish liras , zero penny**.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NumberFormatter` `SPELLOUT` constant doesn't handle the decimals.

You can use the following custom function to display a float number amount spell out like *(with the currency details)*:

```
function wc_spellout_amount( $amount, $country_code = 'tr' ) {
    $formatter = new NumberFormatter($country_code, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
    $formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%financial");

    $amounts = explode('.', (string) $amount); // Separating decimals from amount

    $output  = $formatter->format($amounts[0]);
    $output .= ' ' . _n('turkish lira', 'turkish liras', $amounts[0], 'woocommerce');
    $output .= ', ' . $formatter->format($amounts[1]);
    $output .= ' ' . _n('penny', 'pennies', ( $amounts[1] > 0 ? $amounts[1] : 1 ), 'woocommerce');

    return $output;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

**Usage:** Then you will use it as follows in your code:

```
echo wc_spellout_amount( $order->get_total() );
```

Tested and works.

Comment: works perfectly. Thx a lot. how can i get result uppercase letter ?

Comment: @MusaBaltacı I just updated the function… To get result in uppercase letters use `echo strtoupper( wc_spellout_amount( $order->get_total() ) );`